# Add days on INSERT MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I am (unsuccessfully) trying to set as default value to DATETIME a date based on another column that uses CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as default, but adding some days.

On MSSQL I used to do `(dateadd(day,(5),[start_date]))` as a "Computed Column Specification" to set the column `end_date` 5 days more that `start_date` column.

So, when I perform an INSERT I would like that `start_date` were set to `NOW();` and `end_date` were set to `[NOW(); + X days]`

Is this even possible on MySQL?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of MySQL 8.0.13, you can use expressions for default values.

It would allow you to call functions in your default. However, I do not believe you have the ability to query other columns (give it a try?)

You can use something like:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  ...
  start_date DATE      DEFAULT (CURRENT_DATE),
  end_date DATE        DEFAULT (CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 5 DAY),
  ...
);
```

Do note the enclosing parenthesis is required for indicating it is an expression and not a literal.

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html

Comment: Yes, but without specifying it, I mean, as a default value. This DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 DAY) seems to be invalid as default value for the column. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @JoseLuisMartinez, Try `SELECT VERSION();`. If it's less than 8.0.13, this feature of using expressions in the DEFAULT clause is not yet implemented.

Comment: Also the syntax should be `INTERVAL 5 DAY` instead of `INTERVAL 5 DAYS`.

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much. It has to be done by SQL so I was not able to do through phpmyadmin interface. Very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

If you use an older version of MySQL and cannot use expressions in the `DEFAULT` clause as shown in the other answer, you can do this with a trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger BEFORE INSERT ON t1
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  SET NEW.start_date = CURDATE();
  SET NEW.end_date = CURDATE() + INTERVAL 5 DAY;
END
```